# Looking for a way to remote manage a completely headless system

Tags: windows, remote-access, headless

I have an old WS that I turned into a dedicated plex transcoding server. It is running windows 7(64 bit) and has no onboard or dedicated graphics installed( to lower the power usage of an always on system ).

I am looking for a  way to remotely run command lines/bats and I need to be able to kill the process and restart them.

I have tried windows remote desktop, and teamviewer

I can re-install the gpu if needed to do system updates / set up newer software. If there are some software packages to do this that I am not aware of.

Comment: Teamviewer, remote desktop, VNC etc etc all seem like good options? But if those worked perfectly for you then you would not be posting this question. So can you please add why not to use them or why you want to avoid a particular thing?

Comment: The issue is that when you remote in there is nothing rendering the desktop so the screen is black. Leaving me unable to control the computer.

Comment: Ah. I have used RD and TV in the past, but always with on motherboard graphics present. So I expected a 640x480 screen. Ok, that leaves a few options: 1) Windows terminal server might work (also never treid that without GPU).   2) Remote using telnet/ssh.  3) psexec (used to manage windows [servers] from the command line..  4) Another OS which does not need a graphics card. E.g. Zen or vmware ESX (with windows running as a virtualised guest OS). 5). Since it it a workstation and not a desktop maybe it has iLO or DRAC management?

Comment: I think ssh might be the easiest option as the board doesnt support iLO or DRAC and psexec would be tricky since the old WS and my current have the exact same name. I'll go install a ssh server on it and see how well it works. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: According to this Microsoft [blog post](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2009/03/03/top-10-rdp-protocol-misconceptions-part-1/), RDP doesn't need a physical graphics card: "RDP plugs into the Windows graphics system the same way a real display driver does, except that, instead of being a driver for a physical video card, RDP is a virtual display driver". Are you *sure* you can't use Remote Desktop? (You can't use TeamViewer because it *does* depend on the physical GPU.)

Comment: @steamace1 Changing the computers name is trivial though. And probably should be done for no other name than to easily distinguish between the two systems.

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator   So my issue with WRD is that the user account that is being ran headless is a under privileged user that has a password disabled to automatically login on the event of a power failure / reboot. If i try to RD in I can only access the admin account which kicks the server offline.
Edit:  I also have never tried it without the graphics card installed.

Comment: Add the user to the `Remote Desktop Users` group to permit access via RDP. It's trivial to configure [automatic logon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows) of an account that has a password.

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator , Well it wasn't super straight forward but I did manage to get everything auto logging back in with a password. But for some reason I cannot save my mapped network drive credentials between reboots. I am temporary using a bat to unmap / remap at the start now but it seems a bit weird that it just quit saving them. Would you have any suggestions for that, as I would prefer not to have shared drive passwords in plain text.

Comment: That's an excellent [question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try Remote Desktop (again). It will work fine on a system without a graphics adapter as confirmed by this Microsoft [blog post](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2009/03/03/top-10-rdp-protocol-misconceptions-part-1/):

> "RDP plugs into the Windows graphics system the same way a real display driver does, except that, instead of being a driver for a physical video card, RDP is a virtual display driver".

From your comment:

*...[M]y issue with [Remote Desktop]...is that the user account...is a under privileged user that has [its] password disabled to [permit] automatically login on the event of a power failure / reboot.*

I understand the account doesn't have a password so that Windows can login to the account automatically, but this also prevents using the account for Remote Desktop due to the security policy preventing network connections using accounts with blank passwords.

This can easily be solved by assigning a password which will enable Remote Desktop for that account (after you add it to the `Remote Desktop Users` group). Then configure the computer to [automatically logon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows) using the account and it's password.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has [`Enter-PSSession`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession).  It's going to take some work to get the computers to trust each other and configure Windows 7 for [remote management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands) but it's doable.